# qt creator horizontal mouse scroll not working (Shift + mouse wheel)

Tags: scroll, qt-creator, horizontal-scrolling

qt creator horizontal mouse scroll not working (Shift + mouse wheel), how can I fix this?

- Qt Creator 6.0.2
- Based on Qt 6.2.2 (MSVC 2019, 64 bit)
- Windows 10

and

- Qt Creator 7.0.1
- Based on Qt 6.3.0 (GCC 11.2.0, 64 bit)
- Arch Linux x86_64

Comment: AFAIK, this is not supported in Windows by default (I tested this in Explorer and Notepad), but have a look here https://superuser.com/questions/13763/horizontal-scrolling-shortcut-in-windows

Comment: yes notepad doesn't support it but in vs code it works and most importantly in Linux (in Qt Creator) horizontal scrolling doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ALT + Scroll Wheel. On Manjaro it works for me.

Comment: This really worked for me and allowed me to do horizontal scrolling but how do you change the Alt key to Shift ?

Comment: I can confirm this works on Windows too. I have been using QtCreator for ages and I did not know about this. Perfect! :)

Comment: Yet another important oservation: this works in all QtWidget apps by default too.